# C++ stl map lookup time when key is vector?

Tags: c++, data-structures, std

If i am using a vector of max size N as a key for std::map will the key lookup time/access time be O(1) or O(N)?
Same question but if i use string of size N, question for both map and unordered_map?

Assume the values to be integers. So we have a map of size N and the map has vector keys with integers as values. The vectors are also of size N. Does this make the lookup time O(N)?

I was caught off-guard when asked this in an interview months ago, and i'm really not sure but i think it should be O(N).

Comment: see `Complexity` here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: and here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Comment: you must be clear about what is `N` when talking `O(N)`. Typically for lookup in a map, one considers the number of elements in the map, and ignores other factors. If you are asked for complexitiy of comparing strings or vectors depending on their size the answer is in the above two links

Comment: The lookup time for a `std::map` is `O(log N)` where N is the size of the map. If you also want to include the size of the vector, then you have two different parameters.

Comment: @john OP's `N` is the size of the _key_, not the size of the map.

Comment: The time comparing keys (which happens a lot, when accessing or manipulating the map) is, in principle, `O(N)`.  In practise though, it's likely to be a lot less, because you'll get a few elements into the vectors being compared and encounter a difference (at which point you know what the result of the comparison is).

Comment: N is both the size of the map(N keys) and the size of the vector(N elements). S

Comment: So now when I look up a key, the key being sized N does it compare each element of the key(vector)?

Answer (score 0):

One bound is O(N * logN) because of vector comparison in linear time and map lookup in logarithmic time. But you have to be careful here with Big-O notation. Another bound is O(2^N) or O(ackermann(N,N)) because of the way how O(f) is defined.

I suspect that the tightest bound is well below O(N * logN) because your key lookup will not be Theta(N). For example, if comparing `baaaaaaaaa` with an entry `caaaaaaaaa` you don't need 10 comparisons to figure out that the first is < than the latter. You need just one.

So if the map's tree is roughly balanced (which an rb tree is) **and** your key vector has only binary values (0 or 1) half the values are expected to start with 0 and half with 1. This means on the first branch, half the values will be decided after only ~1 comparisons, a quarter after ~2 comparisons and so forth, an eighth after ~3 comparisons, and so forth. The first comparison has [expected constant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/430766) cost. I don't know how the others behave but I suspect they follow a similar pattern. So it stands to reason that the time complexity can be a approximated with a better term than the pessimistic O(N * logN).

If the key values are not binary, the bounds can be arbitrarily bad again and all bets are off.